# Does the EASA LAPL(A) have a FAA equivalent?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, lapl

I have an EASA LAPL (A) fixed wing pilots license and would like to know what the equivalent FAA license would be.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about their equivalence (meaning one cannot fly in US with a LAPL right way), but the closest that comes is the Recreational Pilot license.

The [requirements](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/part-61/subpart-D) are roughly similar:

- 30 hours flying experience; however, the [FAA requires 3 hours of solo flying](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.99) and cross country requirements are slightly different.

The [limitations](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.101) are also roughly similar:

- Recreational pilot license doesn't allow the pilot to have more than one passenger, while the LAPL does (upto three).

Answer (score 1):

The new EASA LAPL licenses (A, S, etc.) are sub-ICAO level licenses, meaning that they do not conform to ICAO standards (required minimum training hours, for one).

Since ICAO is normally the framework under which various countries accept each others' licenses, there is currently no recognition of LAPL outside of EASA member states.