# What FAA license does the EASA LAPL convert to?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, pilot-certification, lapl

I have read about getting a FAA licence to 'piggyback' with a EASA PPL(A).
Is there a similar route for a EASA LAPL(A) licence.
I assume if there is then there would be the same restrictions ie Max 4 on board, No night flying or IFR flying allowed, simply VFR, which would not be a problem for me.

Basically, I am looking to take a flying holiday (vacation - let's not upset the U.S. readers) - not hour building to gain any additional licences or ratings.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, an LAPL license isn't ICAO compliant. This is [from the UK CAA](https://www.caa.co.uk/General-aviation/Pilot-licences/Introduction-to-licensing/Introduction-to-licensing/):

> Licences which do comply are known as ICAO licences and those which
>   do not are known as non-ICAO licences. Non-ICAO licences are not fully
>   recognised internationally, and therefore are only valid for use
>   within certain states or Europe; for example, the LAPL is only valid
>   in Europe.

That means that the FAA won't recognize it and you can't use it to [get an FAA PPL under 14 CFR 61.75](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/183/62), because that requires you to hold an ICAO compliant private pilot's license. As far as I know, there's no other way to convert a foreign license to a US one (a sport or recreational pilot license would be [the closest US equivalent](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22304/62)).

Comment: Added note that the FAA sport license has a limit of one passenger.